# SQL inner join on pagination

Tags: php, sql

I have two table - Item and Order.

```
Item  
=====================
ID, ItemName 


Order 
========================
orderID, ID , status
```

I want to join the table by using inner join :

```
SELECT Order.orderID, Order.ID, Item.ItemName
FROM Order
INNER JOIN Item
ON Order.ID=Item.ID
```

But the problem i need to do pagination on php.

I have the code but i don't know how to modify it as my sql is not very good.

Here is the code (I have modify it and able to display with '*' but have no idea how to apply inner join as above on below code):

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM 
(
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Order.orderID) AS RowNumber, *, TotalRows=Count(*) OVER()
FROM Order WHERE status=1
) _tmpInlineView
WHERE RowNumber >= 20 AND status=1 ORDER BY Order.orderID
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your inner join query , where does PERSONS table come in use ?? you should name it Item i guess

Comment: Oops, I have edited the inner join. Sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your join below Order table:

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM 
(
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Order.orderID) AS RowNumber, Order.orderID, Order.ID, Item.ItemName, TotalRows=Count(*) OVER()
FROM Order INNER JOIN Item
ON Order.ID=Item.ID WHERE status=1
) _tmpInlineView
WHERE RowNumber >= 20 ORDER BY _tmpInlineView.orderID
```

Comment: This is what i get :   

[SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'orderID'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'orderID'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 8156 [code] => 8156 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]The column 'orderID' was specified multiple times for '_tmpInlineView'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]The column 'orderID' was specified multiple times for '_tmpInlineView'. )

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
      SELECT TOP 20 * FROM 
        (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Order.orderID) AS RowNumber, ORDER.*, 
Count(1) OVER() as TotalRows
        FROM ORDER INNER JOIN Item ON Order.ID=Item.ID
         WHERE status=1
        ) _tmpInlineView
        WHERE RowNumber >= 20 ORDER BY orderID
```

OR Try this

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM ORDER INNER JOIN Item ON Order.ID=Item.ID WHERE status=1
    ORDER BY Order.orderID 
    OFFSET ( @PageNo - 1 ) * @RecordsPerPage ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @RecordsPerPage ROWS ONLY

The following are the limitations of using Offset Fetch:
1) Fetch Next can't be used standalone, it requires Offset
2) Offset can't be used standalone, it requires order by
3) Top can't be combined with offset fetch next in the same query expression
```

Comment: Hi, 
I tried and i get this error : Invalid column name 'status'

And when i try to change status to Order.status 

I get  : The multi-part identifier "Order.status" could not be bound